# Overloading generic extension methods with constraints - the Func pattern

Tags: c#, generics

There is a really cool pattern used by many GUI frameworks to ensure things are coded correctly:

```
interface IBase1 {}
interface IBase2 {}

class Base1 : IBase1
{
    public int x { get; set; }
}
class Base2 : IBase2
{
    public int y { get; set; }
}

static class Helpers
{
    public static void ToProp<T,Y> (this T obj, Func<T, Y> getter)
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b1 = new Base1();
        var b2 = new Base2();

        b1.ToProp(b => b.x);
        b2.ToProp(b => b.y);
    }
}
```

The wonderful thing here is that when you type `b => b.x`, Visual Studio will give you IntelliSense, and the compiler will complain if you tried to access an incorrect property. I see this used often in MVVM frameworks. They will often take the `b => b.x` as an expression tree and parse out the name of the parameter in order to properly raise the notify property change message.

I would like to extend this, and replace the ToProp definition with the following, basically having two code paths depending on the base interface:

```
static class Helpers
{
    public static void ToProp<T,Y> (this T obj, Func<T, Y> getter)
        where T : IBase1
    {
        // Do something custom for 1
    }

    public static void ToProp<T, Y>(this T obj, Func<T, Y> getter)
        where T : IBase2
    {
        // Do something custom for 2
    }
}
```

This won't compile as is - the two `ToProp` invocations both fail with ambiguous method resolution errors. This is a well known problem on SO - object constraints are not part of the method resolution process (see Lipert's [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx) for example).

But I can't help but wonder if there isn't a way. I tried replacing `this T obj` with `this Base1 obj`, for example, but in that case you loose the ide's support for property resolution, also it would be possible to write `b1.ToProp(b => b.y)`. That could be caught with a runtime exception, I suppose. I tried implicit conversions too - but that isn't part of the method resolution process, unfortunately.

This came up because I was extending the ReactiveUI framework to work with Caliburn.Micro. ReactiveUI has this very nice extension method ToProperty which takes a ReactiveUI ViewModel. With minor modifications I can alter that code to use a Caliburn.Micro view model. However, I then run into the ambiguous method issues above. In the meantime I just call the Caliburn.Micro method `ToPropertyCM`.

Anyone know a clever avenue I should chase to make something like this work? And be extensible to new base class types?

**Edited** Fixed up example to show that it is a simple interface that I'm interested in. BTW, I tried the wrapper method b.c. if I understand method resolution it should allow you to do constraint checking on the types of a template argument as part of the resolution process. But, as I mentioned, the implicit type conversion doesn't work during resolution.

Comment: As you mentioned it in your text, do you actually just want to extract the property from the expression?

Comment: Yes, that is how I would get the property name... Just parse the expression tree (most implementations currently have a pretty limited parsing capability).

Answer (score 2):

Just don't make the methods generic with respect to that type:

```
public static void ToProp<Y>(this Base1 obj, Func<Base1, Y> getter)
{
    // Do something custom for 1
}

public static void ToProp<Y>(this Base2 obj, Func<Base2, Y> getter)
{
    // Do something custom for 2
}
```

If it's important that these methods be generic with respect to that type, then you'll need to change the signature in some way to resolve the ambiguity.  The most effective way of doing this would be to change the name.  If the behavior is being personalized for those two types then they're conceptually doing something at least *slightly* different, so you should be able to reflect that in the name of the method.

Comment: This solution has already been discarded by the OP, because you lose the strong typing of obj. You can't invoke members of derived classes in the delegate.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I am not certain that this is the solution that has been discarded: it looks to me that OP's solution that he did not like was `ToProp<T,Y>(this Base1 obj, Func<T, Y> getter)`

Comment: @ThomasLevesque The edited paragraph addresses that case, although as per dasb's comment, I'm not quite sure if this is actually the case he discarded.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, actually, that signature would enable access to members of derived classes, but it would require to specify type parameters explicitly

Comment: @ThomasLevesque However you don't know that the specified type is actually the type of the instance provided as the first parameter; and so static type safety goes out the window entirely, as the OP mentions.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. This is a good idea, but it won't work. It means I can only get at properties of type Base1 and Base2, and I can't do derived classes. I really should have added interfaces to the question... Let me fix that up. apologies for not having a clear question! It will take me a few minutes to fix this.

Comment: @Gordon See the final paragraph; if this isn't an option, then you'll want to change the signatures in some way; the method name is likely the most appropriate way to do so.

Comment: Yes - I am currently changing the method names.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that you are actually only interested in parsing the expression to get the property name, I’ll present you a different method instead of focusing on your code which, as the discussion on Servy’s answer showed, won’t really work.

So, I do this myself a lot for MVVM. My view models implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and to raise the `PropertyChanged` event, I need to specify the name of the property that changed in the event arguments. As this is a string, there is no inherent check that the property name is actually correct. So just like you said, I use a lambda expression to specify the property in a type-safe matter (with IntelliSense support), and then parse the expression tree to extract the property name.

As this is something I only need with `INotifyPropertyChanged`, I have the implementation in my base view model which implements both the interface and a quick method for raising the event with a lambda expression.

So I don’t actually use an extension method. This has the benefit, that I don’t need to know the type of the property owner. For example if I want to throw the event for `something.Name`, I don’t need to know what type `something` is. Instead of running this:

```
viewModel.OnPropertyChanged(viewModel.GetPropertyNameFor(vm => vm.Name));
```

I just do

```
viewModel.OnPropertyChanged(() => viewModel.Name);
// or actually
this.OnPropertyChanged(() => Name);
```

So the expression we are looking at looks like this: `() => obj.Property`. That is a `Expression<Func<T>>` where `T` is the type of the property—something that doesn’t interest us actually.

The extraction actually happens in a static method and looks like this:

```
static string ExtractPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
{
    if (propertyExpression == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyExpression");

    MemberExpression memberExpression = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpression == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("The expression is not a member access expression.", "propertyExpression");

    PropertyInfo property = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (property == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("The member access expression does not access a property.", "propertyExpression");

    return memberExpression.Member.Name;
}
```

And that’s already all there is to do:

```
var obj = new {
    Foo = 123,
    Bar = "baz"
};

Console.WriteLine(ExtractPropertyName(obj.Foo)); // Foo
Console.WriteLine(ExtractPropertyName(obj.Bar)); // Bar
```

All that follows is just some helper methods in the base view model that allow calling `OnPropertyChanged(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)` etc.

---

You can actually make that function an extension method just by changing its signature:

```
static string ExtractPropertyName<T> (this INotifyPropertyChanged obj, Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
{ … }
```

Then you can call the method on any object that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` which your framework very likely does.

Your example could look like this then:

```
var b1 = new Base1();
var b2 = new Base2();

// in a static Utils class
Utils.ExtractPropertyName(() => b1.x);

// or as an extension method to INPC
someViewModel.ExtractPropertyName(() => b2.y);
```

Comment: Clever, and thanks! I've already got the expression coding going - but the idea of implementing this in the base class is very nice. In ExtractPropertyName don't you need to do a type check to make sure it works for that object?

Comment: In my particular case this isn't an option- I'm adding functionality to existing frameworks - and while I could re-implement their base classes (they use interfaces), but this is a lot of work. I also don't really control the other people's frameworks. But if I was in complete control this would work because I'd implement the method on the two different objects, and then custom code would be run for each object, by definition.

Comment: `ExtractPropertyName` doesn’t need a type check for the object. It requires you to pass a `Func<T>` expression, and the checks inside make sure that the expression is actually a member expression that refers to a property. Every member expression that refers to a property will automatically work then—there are no further type restrictions to the object.

Comment: Also, the method is static, so you could always just put it in some utility class and call it directly: `Util.ExtractPropertyName(obj.Foo)`. That way you can still use it anywhere. You could also make this an extension method of one of your framework’s interface—or even `INotifyPropertyChanged` I guess.